# Ruby Rails Tagging - many to many relation with 3 tables - in middle (through) table double rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have this situation in Ruby on Rails (5.0)

- Many tags have many conditions
- In case one same condition for more tags - then must be determined concrete percentage partition

Examples

- Tag "work" has condition "VS Code"  percent 40
- Tag "paid" has condition "VS Code"  percent 60
- Tag "work" has condition "Calc"     percent 100
- Tag "funny" has condition "Youtube" percent 100

### Main table Tag

```
table structure---------------------  

      t.string :name
      t.datetime :valid_from
      t.datetime :valid_to

with model--------------------------

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :groupings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :groupings

    has_many :tag_conditionings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tag_conditions, through: :tag_conditionings

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_conditions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_conditionings
end
```

### Another table Tag_condition

```
table structure---------------------  

condition:string

with model--------------------------

class TagCondition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag, optional: true
end
```

## And between table Tag_conditioning (with percent)

```
table structure---------------------  

      t.references :tag_condition, foreign_key: true
      t.references :tag, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :percent

with model--------------------------


class TagConditioning < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag_condition, optional: true
  belongs_to :tag, optional: true
end
```

I have one view with 2 nested forms - if i understand right

```
<%= form_for(tag) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>


  <%= f.fields_for :**tag_conditions** do |c| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.label :**condition** %>
      <%= c.text_field :**condition** %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :**tag_conditionings** do |c| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.label :**percent** %>
      <%= c.text_field :**percent** %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :valid_from %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :valid_from %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :valid_to %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :valid_to %>
  </div>
```

### Controller - tags_controllers.rb

```
 def new
    @tag = Tag.new
    @tag.tag_conditions.build
    @tag.tag_conditionings.build
  end

  def create
    @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)

     respond_to do |format|
       if @tag.save
         format.html { redirect_to @tag, notice: 'Tag was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tag }
       else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @tag.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end

private
    def tag_params
      params.require(:tag).permit(:name, :percent, :valid_from, :valid_to, tag_conditions_attributes: [:condition], tag_conditionings_attributes: [:percent])
    end
```

Everything is ok, **only** in table tag_conditionings i have double INSERTS and therefore double ROWS

```
INSERT INTO "tags" ("name", "valid_from", "valid_to", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "sdf"], ["valid_from", "2020-05-08 19:56:00"], ["valid_to", "2020-05-08 19:56:00"], ["created_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.811745"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.811745"]]                     
**first INSERT**
INSERT INTO "tag_conditionings" ("tag_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 14], ["created_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.843693"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.843693"]]                                                                                                                                      

INSERT INTO "tag_conditions" ("condition", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["condition", "50sd"], ["created_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.865495"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.865495"]]                                                                                                                               
**second INSERT**
INSERT INTO "tag_conditionings" ("tag_condition_id", "tag_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_condition_id", 16], ["tag_id", 14], ["created_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.919774"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-08 19:56:55.919774"]]
```

I am amateur newie, can you help me? **What I have wrong?** I spent many hours for googling, reading, testing, but zero result.

Thank you very much

Ivanhoe

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting two additional rows in the `tag_conditionings` is that rails will implicitly create rows in the join table when you have a `has_many through:` association:

```
Tag.first
   .tag_conditions
   .create(some_attribute: 'some_value')
```

The above create 1 row in `tag_conditions` and 1 row in `tag_conditionings`.

The same applies when you are using nested attributes:

```
Tag.create(
  tag_conditions_attributes: [{ some_attribute: 'some_value' }]
)
```

If you want to create the join table entity explicitly and the joined entity you need to nest the nested attributes:

```
class TagConditioning < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag_condition, optional: true
  belongs_to :tag, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_conditions
end

Tag.create(
   tag_conditioning_attributes: [
      { 
        percent: 50,
        tag_condition_attributes: [
           { some_attribute: 'some_value' }
        ]
      }
   ]
)
```

In the form you do this by nesting the call to `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_with(model: @tag) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :tag_conditionings do |conditionings| %>
    <%= conditionings.number_field :percent, in: 1..100 %>
    <%= conditionings.fields_for :tag_conditions do |tc| %>
      <%= tc.text_field :conditions %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

And you whitelist the nested-nested attributes through:

```
def tag_attributes
  params.require(:tag)
        .permit(
           :foo, 
           :bar,
           tag_conditionings_attributes: [
              :percent,
              tag_conditions_attributes: [
                :conditions 
              ]
           ]
         )
end
```

I really would not recommend nesting deeper then this as the complexity level just gets insane. The alternative is setting up separate API endpoints and using ajax calls to update the "nested" records in a way that's seamless to the user but actually atomic.

Comment: Hallo Max, thank you very much for concrete informations. I try implementated your suggest. Maybe some detail is wrong yet. `params.require(:tag).permit(:name, :valid_from, :valid_to, tag_conditionings_attributes: [ :percent, tag_conditions_attributes: [ :condition ] ] )` is not function because tag_conditions are not tag_conditions_**attributes** but only tag_conditions   **How can i change from tag_conditions to tag_conditions_attributes?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: When I implemented everything above, then **I have not INSERT to table tag_condition**. I have insert only to tables tag and tag_conditioning. (byebug) tag_params **Unpermitted parameter: tag_conditions**                                                                                   ```<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"cccc", "tag_conditionings_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"percent"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true> ``` **<<tag_conditions_attributes is missing**